# Form in ASP.NET c# clearing values of fields on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I took an existing contact form (that works) and plugged it into a new project and now on submission, the field values get cleared during the postback. There is no initialization kinds of stuff during Page_Load where they would be reset and no controls like UpdatePanel on the page either.

I was having a similar issue with the selected index of a drop down list control being cleared during a postback as well on a different page. I was curious if anyone has ever run into a similar issue due to some sort of setting, etc.

Comment: Make sure you didn't disable the ViewState and all the relevant controls have `runat="server"`.

Comment: Thanks, if anything I've enabled it a bunch of places haha, just trying anything to get it to work. But I do have it enabled in the web config.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply copied the page and it's code behind to your new project then the problem is most likely that the name space of the new page/code behind no longer matches up.  So when the post back occurs it doesn't actually load the code behind file at all.  (Easy to test as no break points would be hit in the page_load method.)

The "simple" fix is to delete the page, the use the standard way of adding a new one into your project.  Then copy/paste the code making sure NOT to overwrite the namespace piece.

The "complicated" fix is to look at the namespace parts on both the .aspx page, code behind and designer files and hand fix them to work with the namespace of your existing project to ensure they all match up.

**Main areas to check include:**
1st line of the .aspx file.  Specifically the part within `Inherits="..."` and `CodeBehind="..."`

`namespace` part of the code behind file should match the first part of the `Inherits` piece.  Essentially Inherits will include the class name.  Same for designer.

Comment: This was all changed when I copied everything over. I have a breakpoint in Page_Load with just a string variable to get the value of one of the textfields and it always is empty.

Comment: @Matt: It would probably help to see your actual code (aspx and codebehind).